# how to union two queries in stored procedure to get result in one row

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure in which I joined two queries. my queries are

```
alter PROCEDURE test

@SDate datetime,
@EDate datetime
```

As

```
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
(Select count(quoteid) as TotalQuote, sum(totalamount) as QuoteAmount from dbo.QuoteBase
where CreatedOn BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate) 
union All

(select  count(salesorderid)as TotalOrders, sum(totalamount) as OrderAmount from dbo.SalesOrderBase Where
CreatedOn BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate)
```

and I got result in to column

```
Total Quote    Quote Amount
17                   700
118                 5000
```

but I want result like

```
Total Quote    Quote Amount    Total Orders   Order Amount
  17               700              118           5000
```

If anyone have idea please share with me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_test

      @SDate DATETIME 
    , @EDate DATETIME

AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
          t.TotalQuote
        , t.QuoteAmount
        , t2.TotalOrders
        , t2.OrderAmount
    FROM (SELECT a = 1) a
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 
              TotalQuote = COUNT(quoteid)
            , QuoteAmount = SUM(totalamount)
        FROM dbo.QuoteBase
        WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate
    ) t
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 
              TotalOrders = COUNT(salesorderid)
            , OrderAmount = SUM(totalamount) 
        FROM dbo.SalesOrderBase
        WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate
    ) t2

END
```

*Update:*

```
SELECT 
      t.TotalQuote
    , t.QuoteAmount
    , t2.TotalOrders
    , t2.OrderAmount
FROM (
    SELECT 
          TotalQuote = COUNT(quoteid)
        , QuoteAmount = SUM(totalamount)
    FROM dbo.QuoteBase
    WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate
) t
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
          TotalOrders = COUNT(salesorderid)
        , OrderAmount = SUM(totalamount) 
    FROM dbo.SalesOrderBase
    WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN @SDate AND @EDate
) t2 ON 1 = 1
```

Comment: No need for the `(SELECT a = 1) a` ?

Comment: If you use `count` without a `group by`, you'll always get one row back, even if the table is empty

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `cross join` instead of a `union`:

```
select  q1.TotalQuote
,       q1.QuoteAmount
,       q2.TotalOrders
,       q2.OrderAmount 
from    (
        ... first query ...
        ) q1
cross join
        (
        ... second query ...
        ) q2
```